# How to get string between two underscores?

Tags: python, regex

```
str = "IV_04.03.2019-10-56-45_example_c584536f-ab26-40ce-b5b6-386f755ba747_1.csv"
```

i want to extract `example` part and this `c584536f-ab26-40ce-b5b6-386f755ba747`

Comment: The two last underscores?? Because there are other substrings between underscores

Comment: i want to extract example and c584536f-ab26-40ce-b5b6-386f755ba747

Comment: fyi: 'c584536f-ab26-40ce-b5b6-386f755ba747' looks like a text book example for using a regex.

Comment: Do you need to extract `04.03.2019-10-56-45` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "IV_04.03.2019-10-56-45_example_c584536f-ab26-40ce-b5b6-386f755ba747_1.csv"
s1= str.split("_")[2]
s2= str.split("_")[3]
print (s1)
print (s2)
```

output:

```
example
c584536f-ab26-40ce-b5b6-386f755ba747
```

Comment: @Abdullah Ahsan said `example` also ought to be extracted.

Comment: got it thanks for the help.

Comment: you're welcome @AbdullahAhsan

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> "IV_04.03.2019-10-56-45_example_c584536f-ab26-40ce-b5b6-386f755ba747_1.csv".split("_")[1:-1]
['04.03.2019-10-56-45', 'example', 'c584536f-ab26-40ce-b5b6-386f755ba747']
```

This extracts all substrings that are surrounded by underscores and do not contain underscores inside.